# elasticsearch parent/child query logic

Tags: elasticsearch

elastic version: 5.0.1

define mapping：

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_parent": {
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "my_child": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "my_parent"
      },
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

add demo data:

POST _bulk

```
{"update": {"_index": "test","_type": "my_parent","_id": "1"}}
{"doc": {"key": 1},"doc_as_upsert": true}

{"update": {"_index": "test","_type": "my_child","_parent": 1,"_id": "11"}}
{"doc": {"key": 11},"doc_as_upsert": true}

{"update": {"_index": "test","_type": "my_child","_parent": 1,"_id": "12"}}
{"doc": {"key": 12},"doc_as_upsert": true}
```

query:

```
POST test/my_parent/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "key": 3
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "has_child": {
                      "type": "my_child",
                      "inner_hits": {
                        "name": "a"
                      },
                      "query": {
                        "term": {
                          "key": 11
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "has_child": {
                "type": "my_child",
                "inner_hits": {
                  "name": "b"
                },
                "query": {
                  "term": {
                    "key": 12
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

result:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "my_parent",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "key": 1
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "a": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 1,
              "max_score": 0.9808292,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_type": "my_child",
                  "_id": "11",
                  "_score": 0.9808292,
                  "_routing": "1",
                  "_parent": "1",
                  "_source": {
                    "key": 11
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "b": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 1,
              "max_score": 0.9808292,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_type": "my_child",
                  "_id": "12",
                  "_score": 0.9808292,
                  "_routing": "1",
                  "_parent": "1",
                  "_source": {
                    "key": 12
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

question here:

Do 'must'\'should'\'must_not' clause have the same meaning between plain search and parent\child search?

Why the result of inner_hits with name 'a' is returned?

Answer (score 0):

`'must'|'should'|'must_not'` clauses  have different meaning. Let me explain you with example of the plain search.

Understand these clause with equivalent SQL query.

**must:** The clause (query) must appear in matching documents and will contribute to the score.

**SQL:** select * from user where country_code = 'US' **AND** state_code = 'NY'
**Query DSL:**

```
POST _search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"term": {"country_code": "US"}},
                {"term": {"state_code": "NY"}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**should:** At least one of these clauses must match, like logical OR.

**SQL:** select * from user where country_code = 'US' **OR** state_code = 'NY'
**Query DSL:**

```
POST _search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {"term": {"country_code": "US"}},
                {"term": {"state_code": "NY"}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**must_not:** Condition must not match the documents.
**SQL:** select * from user where country_code **!=** 'US' **AND** state_code **!=** 'NY'
**Query DSL:**

```
POST _search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": [
                {"term": {"country_code": "US"}},
                {"term": {"state_code": "NY"}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

> Why the result of inner_hits with name 'a' is returned?

Because you put two has_child condition inside the `should` filter. As explain above it is matching the document from (inner_hits.name =a ..) OR ( inner_hits.name=b ..)

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. What confused me is the clauses's behavior between non-parent-query and parent-query。Why the result of inner_hits with name 'a' is returned?

Comment: The query translate to SQL should be: `select * from my_parent left join my_child where (my_parent.key=3 and my_child.key=11) or my_child.key=12`，which means child with key as 11 shouldn't be returned.